# Can i multiple select a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Hi all i want to multiple select the items from a dropdown list. I know it is possible on listbox and also with checkboxes but is there a way i can multiple select by writing a javascript or something else?

Example:

Dropdownlist:

1. Item1
2. Item2
3. Item3
4. Item4

Multiple select result in ddl: Item1,Item3,Item4

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible for DropDwonList. You have to do this yourself. Here is a sample which might help you:
[click me](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_648ec0210100iaw0.html)

Answer (score 0):

DropDownList has two preperties

```
DropDownList1.DataTextField
DropDownList1.DataValueField
```

You can store two values in each. The `DataTextField` will be visible and `DataValueField` will be in the back not visible to the user but you can fetch that as

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you should use a ListBox or CheckBoxList. This is what they are for. It's probably not a good idea to implement a custom interface when there is already a built-in way to do this, as this will most likely surprise the user.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment